# Raspberry PI + Aarch64 + openjdk11

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, arm

I need to use openjdk11 on aarch64 architecture/ Raspberry Pi 3 64bit Debian.

uname -a

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v8+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 17 02:45:42 PDT 2018 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded from https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/ the 64bit openjdk

file java

```
java: sticky ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=620015530195267e6ed011049fccb2d75cd99a95, not stripped
```

I tried run from /usr/local/jdk-11.0.4/bin/java -version or directly with java command.. I get

```
"-bash: /usr/local/jdk-11.0.4/bin/java: No such file or directory"
```

I checked the permissions.. but no problem.

ls -l gives back

```
-rwxrwxrwt 1 pi pi 21062 Jul 11 13:29 /usr/local/jdk-11.0.4/bin/java
```

which java

```
/usr/local/jdk-11.0.4/bin/java
```

Any idea, what is the problem or how could I install openjdk11 version on aarch64/rpi3?

Many thanks,
Szabolcs

I followed that tutorial https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-11-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-debian-9/ just with azul zulu openjdk version.. because that tutorial based on x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here.

```
cd /opt
wget https://cdn.azul.com/zulu-embedded/bin/zulu11.35.36-ca-jdk11.0.5-linux_aarch64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf zulu*tar.gz
mv zulu11.35.36-ca-jdk11.0.5-linux_aarch64 jdk11
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk11
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Add the last two files to your shell profile. Then test it:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.35+36-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.35+36-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```